# What is the difference between "Main (String[] args)" and "Main(string[] args)" in C#

Tags: c#, string, program-entry-point, sharpdevelop

What is the difference between

```
public static void Main (String[] args)
```

and

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
```

in C#? I am using SharpDevelop 4.3.1 as the development environment.

If I am using `string` it is highlighted in red but when I am using `String` it is highlighted in black. Checking online I found out that both `String` and `string` are the same, if so why are they highlighted differently?

Comment: Nope, `string` is a synonymous for `String`.

Comment: The same as between `String` and `string` = none. They are highlighted differently because `String` is name of class and `string` is a keyword aliasing to that class.

Answer (score 0):

String is a class name so you can create n number of object to implement its methods. where as string is reserved word This means that 'string' cannot be used as a variable name by itself.

If for some reason you wanted a variable called string, you'd see only the first of these compiles:

```
StringBuilder String = new StringBuilder();  // compiles
StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();  // doesn't compile
```

If you really want a variable name called 'string' you can use @ as a prefix :

```
StringBuilder @string = new StringBuilder();
```